# Is it possible to decide the fields at run time with MongoRepository in spring data?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongorepository

I have a repository class as mentioned below. I would like to decide the fields to be fetched at run time.

In spring I just imported the interface org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository and created my repository.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

public interface ActiveEmployeeCacheRepository extends MongoRepository<ActiveEmployeeCache, String> {

    @Query(value = "{'employee.employeeNumber': ?0}", fields = "?1")
    public ActiveEmployeeCache findByEmployeeNumber(String employeeNumber, String fields);

}
```

If I run my application with the above code, I am getting below exception.

org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:690)

**I know it looks stupid, but I really need to decide the fields at run time.**

Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: You can't because the @Query are resolved on compile time, i guess the solution is to simply use mappers check this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks) it will give you an idea.

Comment: I tried it little different.


@Query(value = "{'employee.employeeNumber': ?0}", fields = "{'employee.employeeNumber' : ?1}")
    public ActiveEmployeeCache findByEmployeeNumber(String employeeNumber, boolean includeField);


Above one works. It's not 100% true that fields are resolved at compile time. But the problem here is the number of fields. If I have 10+ fields, then i need to declare 10+ parameter for the method.